# Automatic Teller Machine in python problem

Tags: python

**so i want to make simple Automatic Teller Machine in python but there is problem in some line. sorry imnot use english incode**

```
print("Selamat Datang di ATM Saya")
print("Pilih Option :")
print("1. Cek Uang Saya")
print("2. Ambil Uang Saya")
print("3. Tabung Uang Saya")
option=int(input("Silahkan Pilih Option :"))
if option==1:
      print("Uang Kamu Berjumlah Rp.200.000")
elif option==2
      print("Uang Kamu Berjumlah Rp.200.000, Mau Diambil Berapa?")
      print("1. Rp.100.000")
      print("2. Rp.200.000")
    uang_kamu=200000
    option2=int("input"(Option :"))
    if option2==1:
        hasil=uang_kamu-100000
        print("Uang Kamu Sekarang Berjumlah :",hasil)
    elif option2==2:
        hasil2=uang_kamu-200000
        print("kUang Kamu Sekarang Berjumlah :",hasil2)
    else:
            print("Keyword Anda Salah")
elif option==3:
      uang_kamu=200000
      print("Uang Berjumlah Rp.200.000, Mau Nabung Berapa")
      option3=int(input(Masukkan Jumlah Uang :")
      hasil3=uang_kamu+option3
      print("Jumlah Uang Kamu Sekarang Adalah ",hasil3)
else:
      print("Keyword Anda Salah, Mohon Coba Lagi!")
```

Comment: What line? what error are you getting? In any case, it looks like you added too many quotes in the line option2 - int("input"(Option :"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems here.

**First** lines 10-12 are indented wrong, they should be in line with lines 13 and 14.

**Second** a few of the `"`s are in the wrong places: line 14 should be `option2=int(input("Option :"))` instead of `option2=int("input"(Option :"))`  and line 26 should be `option3=int(input("Masukkan Jumlah Uang :"))` instead of `option3=int(input(Masukkan Jumlah Uang :")`

**Third** you need extra brackets on line 26.

**Fourth** you need `:` at the end of line 9.

```
print("Selamat Datang di ATM Saya")
print("Pilih Option :")
print("1. Cek Uang Saya")
print("2. Ambil Uang Saya")
print("3. Tabung Uang Saya")
option=int(input("Silahkan Pilih Option :"))
if option==1:
      print("Uang Kamu Berjumlah Rp.200.000")
elif option==2:
    print("Uang Kamu Berjumlah Rp.200.000, Mau Diambil Berapa?")
    print("1. Rp.100.000")
    print("2. Rp.200.000")
    uang_kamu=200000
    option2=int(input("Option :"))
    if option2==1:
        hasil=uang_kamu-100000
        print("Uang Kamu Sekarang Berjumlah :" + str(hasil))
    elif option2==2:
        hasil2=uang_kamu-200000
        print("kUang Kamu Sekarang Berjumlah :" + str(hasil2))
    else:
            print("Keyword Anda Salah")
elif option==3:
    uang_kamu=200000
    print("Uang Berjumlah Rp.200.000, Mau Nabung Berapa")
    option3=int(input("Masukkan Jumlah Uang :"))
    hasil3=uang_kamu+option3
    print("Jumlah Uang Kamu Sekarang Adalah " + str(hasil3))
else:
    print("Keyword Anda Salah, Mohon Coba Lagi!")
```

After all this and lots of google translate I made your code work.